# ¿En python es posible utilizar un string para invocar una función de un objeto, osea object.variablemethod_string?

Tags: python, variables, function, class

Por ejemplo, si:

```
dia = 'monday'

evento = daily_event.[dia]()
```

, ¿como invoco a la función monday del objeto daily_event, es decir a daily_event.monday(), utilizando un string variabale, sin que dé error?

Comment: La función `exec()` te puede ayudar, solo ten cuidado

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función exec:

```
dia = 'monday'
exec(f'evento = daily_event.{dia}()')
```

Aunque te recomiendo tener un diccionario en lugar de un objeto, ejemplo:

```
daily_event = {
    'monday': funcion,
    ...
}

dia = 'monday'
evento = daily_event[dia]()
```

Espero haber entendido tu pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: sería excelente que explicaras el problema de usar `exec`

Comment: Debe haber una solución mejor que usar `exec`. Sería bueno que analizaras los costos y problemas de la solución.

Answer (score 1):

La función `locals` retorna un diccionario con la tabla de símbolos del módulo actual, lo que incluye una entrada por función, indexada por el nombre de la función.

Entonces, si tenemos

```
def f1(x):
    print("f1", x)

def f2(x):
    print("f2", x)
```

la función `locals()` retorna un diccionario. Usando el nombre de la función puedo recuperarla

```
locals()["f1"]  # Esta es la función
```

y ejecutarla pasando los parámetros que necesite

```
locals()["f1"](4)  # Ejecutando la función f1(4)
```

**Demo**

```
def f1(x):
    print("f1", x)

def f2(x):
    print("f2", x)

for nombre in ["f1", "f2"]:
    locals()[nombre](4)
```

produce:

```
f1 4
f2 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

La función ideal para estos casos es `getattr(object, name[, default])`. Esta función toma como primer argumento el objeto que contiene el atributo (método), como segundo argumento recibe el nombre de este atributo y como tercer argumento permite opcionalmente definir que objeto retornar en caso de este atributo no este definido en el objeto.

El resultado sería:

```py
dia = 'monday'
evento = getattr(daily_event, dia)()
```

**Nota.** Es importante plantear los aspectos en cuanto a seguridad que pueden tener los programas al hacer uso de mecanismos como estos. Si el usuario decide el nombre del método a llamar, teóricamente puede llamar cualquier método del objeto, incluso aquel para el cual tu no estabas preparado. Una posible solución seria tener una whitelist de los métodos que permites llamar, y ver si el método esta dentro de esa whitelist.

Antes de usar cualquier método o función similar, tal como `exec`, `eval`, `setattr`, etc, asegúrate de tener en cuenta algunos aspectos de seguridad.